# How to get a specific URL of Google Sheet automatically

Tags: google-sheets, geturl

I would like to get Google Sheet's URL automatically when there is a specific no. in row A and a sheet name provided as prerequisites.

If there is 15106 in row A and a sheet name --> [See this](https://gyazo.com/33990d619dd758dfc39cdb4305297e6a)

I would like to display it somewhere on the same line with the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing an `onEdit()` function that gets the URL when the sheet is edited - you can tell the function to look for specific ranges and values as you desire. You will have to assemble the url yourself using spreadsheet ID, which you can get using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()`. See Google's [guide to triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) for more information on `onEdit()`.